# JAVA - Insertion Sort Method from ArrayList<String> partially works but doesn't sort the whole list correctly

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, insertion-sort

### Problem

I have a very basic List Array of Strings scanned from a .txt file that I passed onto a insertionSort method to have it sorted **Alphabetically** but it seems to only sort the last 2 or 3 pairs of names towards the end of the Array List. I feel like it may be my while loop in the insertionSort method that is causing this using the compareTo() method to swap indices of Strings stored in the array.

#### Console Output

```
[James, Michael, Adam, Brenda, Margaret, Luke, Chantel, Enzo, Daniel, Lisa] <- original .txt list
[James, Michael, Adam, Brenda, Luke, Margaret, Chantel, Daniel, Enzo, Lisa] <- output
```

I just need help to understand an assignment and why my implementation is not working correctly for my Data Structures & Algorithms class. Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Insert {
    
    public static void insertionSort(List<String> list) {
        for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            String current = list.get(j);
            int i = j-1;
            while ((i > -1) && ((list.get(i).compareTo(current)) == 1)) {
                list.set(i+1, list.get(i));
                i--;
            }
            list.set(i+1, current);
        }
        System.out.print(list);
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        
        File inputFile = new File("customer.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        
        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            data.add(in.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(data);
        
        Insert test = new Insert();
        test.insertionSort(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger to check whether the indices are correct in all places?

Comment: Btw, since `insertionSort()` is a static method you can directly call it in `main()` without having to create that  `test` instance first.

Comment: The `compareTo` method can return a positive integer greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that `String.compareTo()` doesn't necessarily return -1 or 1 for greater or lesser strings but it could be anything < 0 or > 0.

Thus you need to change your condition to: `list.get(i).compareTo(current) > 0`.

The JavaDoc on [`String.compareTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) states:

- If both strings have different characters at index *k* then  `this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)` is returned
- If one string is the prefix of another (e.g. "abc" is the prefix of "abcde") then `this.length()-anotherString.length()`  is returned.

As you can see, those calculations do not necessarily yield -1, 0 or 1.

Here's what the JavaDoc on [`Comparable.compareTo(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) states:

> **Returns** a *negative integer*, zero, or a *positive integer* as this object is *less than*, equal to, or *greater than* the specified object.

It doesn't mention the return values have to be -1, 0 and 1.